# selecting points for plotting in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I need to display points on the graph depending on their year the Data is stored as:

```
{
       Xparam: {1800: …}
       Yparam: {1800: …}
}
```

So from the data according to the year for example 1800, 1801 and so on, I need to get the values of x and y, I'm trying to do it like in code, but the resulting points are the same regardless of the year and are confused into a single area:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAfbn.png)

```
 svg.selectAll('circle').data(data).enter().append("circle")
 .attr("cx", function (d) { return +d[Xparam][year]; })
 .attr("cy", function (d) { return +d[Yparam][year]; })
 .attr("r", radius);
```

How should I select values so for each year I will plot only corresponding points ?

Update: now I`m trying to plot all dots like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        svg.selectAll('circle').data(data).enter().append("circle")
            .attr("cx", +data[i][xParam][year]) 
            .attr("cy", +data[i][yParam][year]) 
            .attr("r", 3);

    }
```

but it still works that dots remain in wrong place

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. Could you update the question to show more of the data structure, i.e. what is nested under the key `1800`? Guidelines for code samples can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: please attach more info. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    let xRange = data.map(d=> +d[xParam][year]);
    x.domain([d3.min(xRange), d3.max(xRange)]);
    xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x));    

    let yRange = data.map(d=> +d[yParam][year]);
    y.domain([d3.min(yRange), d3.max(yRange)]);
    yAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(y));  

    let xLen = d3.max(xRange)-d3.min(xRange);
    let yLen = d3.max(yRange)-d3.min(yRange);

    var p = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data)
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(+d[xParam][year]); })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(+d[yParam][year]); })
        .attr('r', 4 ); 

    p.enter().append("circle")
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(+d[xParam][year]); })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(+d[yParam][year]); })
        .attr('r', 4);
```